# hover over text to show some other text

Tags: javascript, html, hover, nav

I'm having a hardtime to find out how to make a hover effect to show some other text/buttons. i want to make a sort of nav menu with hovers.

please see the picture for more information;

[image]

when you hover to "platenwarmtewisselaar" i want to make a drop down menu over the picture. and when you go to "buizenwarmtewisselaar"or the other text/buttons there will a couple of other options to chose from. how can i insert this into my code?

many thanks!

My code;

```html
  <div id="knoppen">
             <div id="Plaat" onclick="URL" onmouseover="ShowP()">
                 <button id="plaatknop">Platenwarmtewisselaar </button>
            </div>
            <div id="buis">
                <button id="buisknop" onclick="URL"onmouseover="ShowB()">Buizenwarmtewisselaar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="productenplaat">
            <div id="gelast">
                <button id="gelastknop">Gelasteplatenwisselaar  </button>
            </div>
            <div id="gesoldeerdplaat">
                <button id="gesoldeerdknop">gesoldeerde platenwisselaar</button>
            </div>
            <div id="pakkingenplaat">
                <button id="pakkingenknop">platenwisselaar met pakkingen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below code

```css
#menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #424242;
  color: white;
  float: left;
}

#menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background-color: #90CAF9;
}

#menu li.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

#menu ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

#menu ul li.submenu {
  position: relative
}

#menu ul li.submenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    background: #333
}

#menu ul li.submenu:hover ul {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li onClick="Dashboard();">Platenwarmtewisselaar </li>
    <li class="submenu">Buizenwarmtewisselaar &gt;
      <ul>
        <li>Add Employee</li>
        <li>Employee View</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Gelasteplatenwisselaar  </li>
    <li class="submenu">Salary
      <ul>
        <li>Add Employee</li>
        <li>Employee View</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Change Password</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: plz visit the ferarri site and choose "racing" there can u see what i mean :) https://www.ferrari.com/

Comment: let me check there

Comment: @tim this code is help you , what you want to achieve. septeate `div` for background image and set `css` as per require

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but are you talking about this dropdown menu? If so, you can follow the guidelines here.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

Comment: no, i understand that you think that. but i you see the picture, there is some text over this picture. i want to make this visible when i hover over the first word called "platenwarmtewisselaar" when i hover over the second word called "buizenwarmtewisselaar" i want to show some other text over the image

Comment: see the comment above:)